# Use the ref and out keyword on a pointer parameter

Tags: c#, pointers, out, ref

I'm learning C and C#, this question is for C#. Why would you ever use the out and ref keywords on pointers? With pointers you have direct access to the variable. I found this code on msdn:[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664771%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Here is the code:

```
static int value = 20;
public unsafe static void F(out int* pi1, ref int* pi2)
{
  int i = 10;
  pi1 = &i;
  fixed (int* pj = &value)
  {
     // ...
     pi2 = pj;
  }
}
```

Comment: C and C# are drastically different languages, I recommend learning only one of the two at a time. You should ***not*** be using pointers very often in C# but you should be using them in C.

Comment: To answer your specific question, though, I think that's like having a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Are you going to tell us where on MSDN you found it, or should we guess?

Comment: Did you not read the bit on MSDN where it said **this is an example of code you should not write**??? This is sample code showing you *a dangerously broken pattern that you must avoid*, and therefore there is no reason why you would write code like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why would you ever use the out and ref keywords on pointers?

Well, why would you ever use the out and ref keywords, period?  You use the out keyword when you wish to call a method that modifies an existing variable. You use the ref keyword when you wish to call a method that reads and modifies an existing variable. That the variables are of pointer type seems to not be particularly relevant.

If your question is in fact "can you give me an example of realistic code in which you might want to pass a pointer-typed variable by ref?" then I must confess that in ten years of writing C# code I have never used pointers in production code and very rarely use ref, so I don't have an example from personal experience. I can imagine such a thing though. For example, imagine a traditional C-style doubly-linked list. You might have a situation where you want to both read and mutate the head and tail pointers of the list, and do so by passing `ref Link*`s to the head and tail.

Now that you have included the link to where you found this code I note that it explicitly says that **this is an example of dangerously broken code that you must never write**. Asking under what circumstances you would want to write such code is therefore a non-starter. I really don't understand the point of your question now that I see the origin of the code; you should *never* write code like this; that's the whole *point* of the sample.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm a newbie and was just skimming some sites and looking at code, this code gave me the question because it sounded odd to pass these pointers as ref and out when pointers can have access to the variable passed. Maybe it is because I've been feeling it a rather slow process to learn C#, and I don't know if it is just me or it is difficult.

Comment: @somethingSomething: As a newbie, my recommendation is not to spend much time reading about pointers; using pointers means discarding the safety net designed into the language.  C# tries to steer you away from using pointers (with warning signs like the "unsafe" keyword and requiring the /unsafe compiler flag).

Comment: @somethingSomething: Brian is correct; I have been programming in C# for ten years and never once needed to write pointer code in production code. This feature is for only the most advanced scenarios in C# programming so starting there as a newb is probably a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would you ever use the out and ref keywords on pointers?

When you want to provide a pointer to the caller of your function, in the case of `out`, or when you want to be given a pointer and optionally modify it to point to something different, in the case of `ref`.

If you don't need to mutate the *pointer*, and instead only need to dereference the pointer to see what it is pointing to, then you can pass the pointer by value, rather than by reference, which is the behavior whenever `out` and `ref` are not used.

Comment: Behind the scenes, `ref` and `out` are just pointers; they are special pointers that the garbage collector knows about, but they are just pointers. The difference between pointers and `ref`d variables is (1) whether the GC is tracking them or not, and (2) the C# compiler takes care of automatically dereferencing the pointer in the case of `ref` or `out` on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used pointers in C#, but I do use ref parameters with reference types. Reason: clear intentions. If I see a method that takes a *ref* parameter, I know that this parameter will be mutated, so no surprises there.